# Dynamically selecting objects from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, foreach

Myself have a javascript array,

`var array = [{"div0" : [2, 1, 3, 5]}, {"div1" : [1,5,7,8]}, {"div2" : [6,9,11]}];`

which contains json objects as values. I can select each object individually as `array[0].div0`, `array[1].div1`, `array[2].div2`.

But how can I select each object dynamically using jquery `.each()` function so that I can use each objects for different events something like as given in this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/7ctcsz0t/3/)

Comment: That's not JSON, that's Javascript object literals. JSON is a text format to represent object. If your array was `var array = ['{"div0" : [2, 1, 3, 5]}', '{"div1" : [1,5,7,8]}', '{"div2" : [6,9,11]}'];` then it woult be JSON.

Comment: Thank you @Guffa for your concern. Actually the json is dynamically returning from an ajax call. So, it should be a valid json only. Here I simply given a sample to understand.

Comment: In that case it would be the entire array that is delivered as JSON and then parsed into an array of objects. The array would never contain JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following syntax:

```
var id = $(this).prop("id");
var arr = array[index][id];
```